# SQLite3 library routine called out of sequence

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

the following code give me an *library routine called out of sequence* error, but I can't explain me where is the problem. Any ideas ?

```
- (BOOL)insertProduct:(Product *)product inOrder:(Order *)order withAmount:(int)amount
    {
        BOOL ok = NO;
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString * insertSQL;
            int amount = [self getAmountForProduct:product inOrder:order];
            NSLog(@"%i", amount);

            if (amount != -1)
            {
                insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE ARTICOLIPERORDINE SET quantita = %i WHERE ordine = %i AND articolo = '%@'", amount, order.idOrdine, product.codice];
            }
            else
            {
                insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO ARTICOLIPERORDINE (ordine, articolo, quantita) VALUES(%i, '%@', %i)",order.idOrdine, product.codice, 1];
            }

            NSLog(@"%@", insertSQL);
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    ok = YES;
                }
                else
                {
                    ok = NO;
                    NSLog(@"sqlite3 ERROR %s: %@",sqlite3_errmsg(_database), insertSQL);
                }

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                sqlite3_close(_database);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error prepare = %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
            }

        }

        return ok;
    }
```

The log print *Error prepare = library routine called out of sequence*

Comment: What's the return value from your call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2`?

Comment: a BOOL ... question updated

Comment: Actually, `sqlite3_prepare_v2` returns `SQLITE_OK` on success according to the docs, so if you ran the code above, it is guaranteed to fail.   First, you're calling step on fail (`SQLITE_OK` is 0), and second, you call `sqlite3_finalize` on an in-prepared statement.

Comment: sqlite3_close(_database);  should be closed underneath the prepare call.  Aside from this, could you provide the sql statement you're trying to execute, it could be that you're not escaping the sql.

Answer (score 2):

I have one approach.
Before this make sure that you have completed all your sql queries like connection open, close, finalize etc.

> Before run your query actual into your code, execute that query into any database browser, You will see what is missing in your query.

As in my case I wrongly put the column name in query and run the code and I got the error multiple times. I review all the code carefully and execute the query into database browser and I found my mistake.